# Angular-Meteor & iron-router: how to use nested routes?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, iron-router, angular-meteor

I have a collection like so: (many countries, each containing many regions)

```
countries: [
  {
    id: 'qwe123rty456',
    name: 'Australia',
    regions: [
      {
        id: 'poi098uyt765',
        name: 'Western Australia'
      },
      {
        id: '123poi098qwe',
        name: 'Queensland'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Using iron-router I then set a few routes, which work well for 'countries'.

app.js

```
Countries = new Mongo.Collection('countries');

if (Meteor.isClient) {

  angular.module('geo',['angular-meteor', 'ui.router']);

  angular.module('geo').config(function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider){

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $stateProvider
      .state('countries', {
        url: '/countries',
        templateUrl: 'countries.html',
        controller: 'countries_controller'
      })
      .state('country', {
        url: '/countries/:countryId',
        templateUrl: 'country.html',
        controller: 'country_controller'
      })
      .state('region', {
        url: '/countries/:countryId/regions/:regionId',
        templateUrl: 'region.html',
        controller: 'country_controller'
      });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/countries");
  });

  angular.module('geo').controller('countries_controller', ['$scope', '$meteor', '$state',
    function ($scope, $meteor, $state) {

      $scope.countries = $meteor.collection(function() {
          return Countries.find({})
      });

  }]);

  angular.module('geo').controller('country_controller', function($scope, $meteor, $stateParams) {
    $scope.country = $meteor.object(Countries, $stateParams.countryId);
  });

}
```

I can show the list of countries in countries.html and link each country to its own country.html page using the 'countries/:countryId' route.

countries.html

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="country in countries">
    <span>{{country.name}}</span>
    <a href="/countries/{{country._id}}">View</a>
    <span>Regions:</span>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="region in country.regions">
        <span>{{region.name}}</span>
        <a href="countries/{{country._id}}/regions/{{region._id}}">View</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now, I'd like to show each region inside its own 'region.html' page using the '/countries/:countryId/regions/:regionId' route, but that doesn't work, not sure what I need to do.

region.html

```
{{region.name}}
```

Comment: do you get any error in console? what's in your 'region.html' template?

Comment: @shershen I've added the content of region.html